# wrapping webgrid columns into a css

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, webgrid

I want to wrap columns in set of css classes .. some thing like below. However its not working.

```
         @grid.GetHtml(
   @
       <div class="prod_box">
        <div class="center_prod_box">

    columns: grid.Columns(grid.Column("Model"),
         grid.Column("DiscountCost", 
       style:"reduce"))
  ,displayHeader:false
        </div>
   </div> );
```

Comment: I was able to do it using table..